# Need to lookup values in row and give the corresponding month in the column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif, lookup

I need a formula that looks up the number of sales in a month and stage and gives you the highlighted cells in the columns. It has to count the first cell that the sales start in and then if you have 5 sales in Jun, it should populate the month in the column and then move on. Not sure if this is possible or if i need another step in the middle in order to make the formula work.

Sample data:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people that are interested in computers. If you already have a fomula that is not working, we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very doable. Have a look at the countif ans countifs formulae.

Something like
=COUNTIF(C8:C20, H$3)